# What are C++ interpreters used for?

Tags: c++, interpreter

I wonder what is the usage of C++ interpreters. When are they at their best?

Comment: Please clarify. I'm not clear if want to develop an interpreter in c++ or have or use one the interprets C++

Comment: @kenny - I think he was talking about the latter (like Ch)

Comment: @DVK. Yes, right to the point.

Comment: @Alexandre C., you're wrong. Take a look at http://root.cern.ch/ - a C++ interpreter usage there is perfectly justified.

Comment: Completely meaningless question. There is nothing special about a C++ interpreter. If you know what interpreters are used for, and you know what C++ is used for, then you know what purpose a C++ interpreter serves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any interpreter, I would say there are two uses:

- *scripting*
- *experimentation*

I don't see *scripting* catching on for C++, the language is too verbose and there are other more viable alternatives there (python/ruby/shell).

The experimentation however is very attractive. Being able to test a construct on the side is like writing a small dedicated test. The typical example, for me, is the use of regular expressions (in Python):

```
> s = "silly test++/++hello world"
> re.search(pattern, s).groups()
```

I don't want to execute the whole shebang just for the sake of testing that I did write my pattern correctly (the regex compiles) or that it doesn't capture the block I wanted. A quick test catches most of the errors, and I can go on.

Answer (score 4):

Just like ANY interpreted language, they can be used as:

- Embedded scripting language
- Shell scripting language

As an example, please look at Ch usage: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_interpreter#C.2FC.2B.2B_interpreter

Answer (score 2):

I suspect most of them will be made just for curiosity and academic research.

The Advantage of interpreters in general is that you do **not need a compiler** for a specific platform. This way, can run any program on any platform you want - given that there exists an interpreter for that platform.

Another benefit of interpreters is that changes of the source code of the interpreted program can be **immediately** visible to the program, so it makes **debugging** far easier.

Interpreters can give you **dynamic typing** although the C++ has no constructs to make use of it.